# Looking for USB-over-ethernet solution

Tags: windows, software, usb, virtualization

I'm doing development with the Windows phones, but I'd really like to ditch my Windows box.  I have access to a virtual Windows installation in the cloud, but I need to be able to deploy to, and debug on, my phone which is most decidedly ***not*** in the cloud.

I'm looking for software which provides virtual USB ports with client/server TCP/IP support, which supports intercommunication with OS X and Windows.  Anyone heard of anything like that?

Answer (score 3):

I've not found anything that supports OS X as a the server, and Windows as the client.  The best solution I can suggest would be Belkins network USB hub or digi's AnyWhereUSB product.

- http://www.belkin.com/networkusbhub/ - hardware share to win or os x
- http://www.digi.com/products/usb/anywhereusb.jsp#overview - Hardware share to Win
- http://www.virtualserialport.com/products/usb-over-network/ - Win/Linux - OS X coming soon
- http://communities.vmware.com/thread/77230 - Reviews
- http://www.intellidriver.com/products_1.16.html - Win
- http://www.usb-over-network.com/usb-over-network.html - Win
- http://www.fabulatech.com/ - Win/Linux
- http://usbip.sourceforge.net/#about - Linux/Win

Comment: For Mac, Belkin info didn't seem that useful. If you need more recent Mac OS compatibility, better to look at Silex product line: http://silexamerica.com/products/connectivity-solutions/device-networking/usb-parallel-connectivity/ it just doesn't cover the latest Mac OS 10.11 yet.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft's Remote Desktop Connection system has a way to forward arbitrary Plug-and-Play devices to the remote computer. That may work with your phone.

EDIT:
Apparently (according to VxJasonxV) the Mac version of RDC doesn't have these options. Since you have a valid Windows license from your old box, you could run that in a VM (like VirtualBox) and run RDC in there when you need to forward your USB connections over the network.

Look into the 3rd part RDP clients like rdesktop and CORD.  The RDP protocol supports it.  You just need an RDP client that does too.  MS has a habit of leaving features off on non Windows OSes....

Comment: I don't think that's the case for the Mac version, however. I don't see such options in my own.